# Class A function calls a function in Class B , Once it's completed how to get notification to Class A (Android Java)

Tags: java, android, callback

Here is the thing that I need to do.

When the user click on a button on an activity , the app must call a function in different class and sent back a notification to the activity. Then the activity shows those  information in the main screen.

(Let's say the function is to receive firebase data and add it to a sqlite database. Once the data retrieval is complete ,I want to populate those information in the activity )

Is there any way to do this without using Room database

Currently I am writing the method in the activity class and redirect from there to populate data. Here is a example how I currently use it

```
 final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("server/saving-data/fireblog/posts");


ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     int counter = dataSnapshot.size();
  for(int i =0; i<counter;i++){

      Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
         // Add to sqlite data

       if(i=counter) {
         // Populate Data in activity
              } 
        }

  }
```

The Thing i want to do it ,I want to take this function code to a sepeate class and run from the activity and get a callback.

I am a newbie and don't have a idea how to do this. Thank you

Comment: Add a method in your function that is called after data is retrieved in the other class that populates the current class with the data. Also (`i=counter`) is not a correct comparison, use `==` to compare integers.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself.

first you need to create interface , as an example let's take this >

```
    public interface ActionListenerCallback {
    public void onActionSuccess(String successMessage);
    public void onActionFailure(Throwable throwableError);
}
```

After that you need to implement this in the activity where you called the function

```
public class Act_Reps extends AppCompatActivity implements ActionListenerCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   RealtimeDB RDB= new RealtimeDB(this,Id);
         RDB.setCallback(this);
         RDB.callingFunction();
       }


    @Override
    public void onActionSuccess(String successMessage) {
        Log.d("Log", "Message "+ successMessage);
       
    }

    @Override
    public void onActionFailure(Throwable throwableError) {

    }

}
```

Here is the class where the function is called

```
public class RealtimeDB {
     ActionListenerCallback callback;
    
    
        public void setCallback(ActionListenerCallback callback) {
            this.callback = callback;
        }
    
    public void callingFunction(){
    
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             callback.onActionSuccess("Done");
               }
           }, 5000);
          }
    }
```